# How to fit equation to experimental data in Python?

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have experimental data on how diameter (D/D0) of a fluid filament thins over time (t). D/D0 (ydata) and t (xdata) are np arrays.

I would like to fit the data to the following equation:

[image]

In the equation, my known variables are D/D1 = D/D0, D1=D0, and t.

```
D/D0 = np.array([0.129 , 0.1613, 0.1935, 0.2258, 0.2581, 0.2903, 0.3226,0.3548, 0.3871, 0.4194, 0.4516, 0.4839, 0.5161, 0.5484, 0.5806, 0.6129, 0.6452, 0.6774, 0.7097, 0.7419, 0.7742, 0.8065, 0.8387, 0.871 , 0.9032, 0.9355, 1.])
```

```
t = np.array([0.7705, 0.7495, 0.5768, 0.5699, 0.503 , 0.493 , 0.4102, 0.3693, 0.3234, 0.2774, 0.2116, 0.2076, 0.1856, 0.1627, 0.1397, 0.1198, 0.0908, 0.0848, 0.0609, 0.0499, 0.0399, 0.0349, 0.0289, 0.02  , 0.012 , 0.007 , 0.002 ])
```

alpha, a, eta_0 and lambda are unknown to me and I would like to find these values and plot the equation with my experimental data.

How best can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could look into `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` or look for `scipy.optimize.minimize`. Also, what have you tried so far? Show us your code so that we can better help you.

Comment: I have not coded anything yet. I'm new to Python and I wanted to see what package is best to be able to do this.

Comment: In order to test if a particular method and/or software is convenient in your case, please joint to your question an example of data, that is a table of numerical values of D and t. If some parameter (for example D1) is known for this data, joint its value.

Comment: Fair enough. I have included some data.

Comment: It is impossible to discriminate the five parameters alpha, a, eta_0, D_1 and lambda because in the function they are only three independent parameters instead of five. The independent parameters are lambda, a and (eta_0*D_1/alpha).

Answer (score 1):

It is important to replace the three dependent parameters by only one independent parameter into the model equation. Then one can use any software for non-linear regression.

[image]